Chromium browsers: Select Option menu immediately closes after opening when scrolling
I'm encountering an issue with select elements in Chromium-based browsers. Here's the specific problem:

I scroll to the bottom of the page using a mouse with momentum scrolling.
The page reaches the end, but the mouse continues to register scroll events due to momentum.
When I click on a select element, the dropdown menu opens briefly but immediately closes.

This appears to happen because the browser is still processing the momentum scroll events, which interfere with the select element's open state.
How can I prevent this behavior and keep the select dropdown open, even when clicked immediately after scrolling to the bottom of the page?
Firefox doensn't seem to have this problem.

Javascript and performance varies by browser. This doesn't sound like a mission critical failure, so I would give your users a message like "optimized for Firefox" And not worry about those who want to use Chromium
